# Backgrid.js, is it possible to skip rendering of some rows

Tags: backbone.js, backgrid

While it seems I can remove some rows, is it possible to skip rendering of some rows based on some filtering logic?

e.g. don't render a row where `model.get('someProp') == 'X'`

Answer (score 1):

I guess css-solution, e.g. `display:none;`, is ok? Hence, you may play with classNames by just extending the row model you use (backbone native functionality):

```
...
options.row = Backgrid.Row.extend({
  className: function() {
    return this.model.get('property') == 1 ? 'renderme' : 'hideme';
  }
});
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid(options);
```

And then apply whatever styles you want to those classes.
Of course, you could override the `render`-method of `Backgrid.Row` by extending it and check the models property there, but you would end up overriding `Backgrid.Body` as well.

I find using css class names being more flexible multi-purpose solution.

Comment: Not ideal to render something that won't be displayed.  But yeah, that 's one way of doing it, thanks.